# Porting Bluetooth dongle CSR to Android TV box

Tags: bluetooth

I have an Amlogic S905 TV box with no Bluetooth, only WiFi. I started porting the external Bluetooth adapter (CSR 4.0) driver to this box.

I found that the box kernel has inbuilt support for Bluetooth. I checked this using `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` and it shows Bluetooth core ver 2.18

```
1|root@p383: # dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
dmesg | grep -i bluetooth 
<6>[    0.977385@0] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.18
<6>[    0.985193@0] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
<6>[    0.991742@0] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
<6>[    0.996798@0] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
<6>[    1.002071@0] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
<6>[    1.558138@0] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.2
<6>[    1.562707@0] Bluetooth: HCI H4 protocol initialized
<6>[    2.697881@0] Bluetooth: BlueSleep Mode Driver Ver 1.2
<6>[    3.928079@0] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
<6>[    3.933201@0] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
<6>[    3.938501@0] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11 
<6>[    3.942343@0] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
<6>[    3.947854@0] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
<6>[    3.953351@0] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
<6>[    3.958471@0] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
<6>[    3.964573@0] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
```

<sup>[Screenshot of terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjivL.jpg)</sup>

but there is no physical hardware present.
Also, there is a lack of required files like:

- `/system/app/bluetooth.apk`,
- `/system/lib/hw/bluetooth.default.so`,
- `/system/etc/bluetooth`

Then I successfully compiled `btusb.ko` driver in Linux by downloading kernel source code and pasting in `/system/lib`, and driver `btusb.ko` is successfully installed now. The dongle detected in `dmesg log` as

```
#rfkill list
0: hci0: bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

But I am unable to use it because Bluetooth functionality is not on.
I need help with how I paste the required files in the system folder to turn it on.